# Tap Event Handler

Tags: windows-phone-7

It seems there is no **Tap Event handler** for the listbox in **windows phone 7.0** as there is in **7.1**
I found the **SelectionChanged** event however this event causes problem. So is there different event than Tap in 7.0??

```
private void flightlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)  
{    
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Flight"] = flightlist.SelectedItem;    
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/FlightDetail", UriKind.Relative));    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) have a GestureListener that allows you to handle Tap, DoubleTap, and many more events.

It can be attached any element. But regardless, using a custom tap handler, for what the SelectionChanged event is for, is a stupid idea. You should clarify why it "causes problems" for you.

**Update**

Modify your code to this:

```
private void flightlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{    
    if (flightlist.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Flight"] = flightlist.SelectedItem;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/FlightDetail", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    // reset the selected-index, so the user can click on it again, after returning.
    flightlist.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: The problem occurs in this scenario: upon selection i want to navigate to another page, and this i can do.  
However, if i press the back button to go back to the page i navigated from the whole application crashes and exists.

Comment: That would be because your code isn't tombstoned correctly. It's not necessarily related to the ListBox or SelectionChanged event (show some code!). Also, your application won't ever pass validation if it crashes when the user clicks the back button.

Comment: When i used the Tap event in 7.1, the problem didn't occur again. I did test for it and it seemed that after i click the back button, the event is fired again and this leads to navigation to the second page which in turn reads a null variable thus an exception is raised. The selection code is shown in the question above.

Comment: Yeah, that's a obvious problem. You're not checking if flightlist.SelectedItem is null/unset. See my edited answer for details.

Comment: Thank you Claus as always, you're a WP7 expert :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the MouseLeftButtonUp-event of the ListBox and then get the selected item if there is one. Sample code:

```
private void YourListBox_LeftMouseButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    var item = listBox.SelectedItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        //do something with the item
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you buddy, sorry but need to take the best answer :)